# Options in bash commands

Tags: 12.10, command-line, bash

Are the commands' options case sensitive? i.e.

I did

```
rm -r directory
```

And

```
rm -R directory
```

And I got the same results, whereas when I did

```
ls -r directory
```

and

```
ls -R directory
```

I got different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what man pages are for

ls:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/ls.1.html

> -r, --reverse
>                 reverse order while sorting
>
> -R, --recursive
>                 list subdirectories recursively

rm:

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/rm.1.html

> -r, -R, --recursive
>                 remove directories and their contents recursively

So with the command rm, -r and -R are the same, but not so with ls

Answer (score 3):

Yes, almost everything in Linux is case sensitive.

For example, in your [**`ls`**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ls) command,

```
   -r, --reverse
      reverse order while sorting

   -R, --recursive
      list subdirectories recursively
```

Also, like in [**`ln`**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?ln):

```
   -s, --symbolic
      make symbolic links instead of hard links

   -S, --suffix=SUFFIX
      override the usual backup suffix
```

However, sometimes the upper and lowercase letter options are the same, like in [**`rm`**](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?rm):

```
   -r, -R, --recursive
      remove directories and their contents recursively
```

It depends on the command. To best find out if upper and lowercase make a difference, always consult the `man` pages of a command.

Answer (score 0):

The cases only matter if there is another argument in the opposite case.  This is usually how it works, so I would keep the case of the argument the same as what command you want

Comment: Not true, depends on the command